# CSS and hide element

Tags: css, highslide

i need hide pics and **no use**  `display:none`

I use Highlight script for create one gallery , the problem it´s i need only show 4 pics and no the others , the script let click in one pic and show the others with arrows , the problem it´s if i use `display:none` for the other pics and no in the first 4 , the other pics no show finally

I try other possibilities , but no works , i need hide all pics out of the firsts 4 but i can´t use display:none

The Best Regards

Comment: post your code in fiddle?

Comment: The question it´s only if i can´t hide pic without use display:none , no there more code , only about this i need hide pics and no use display:none; , thank´s

Comment: Try `height: 0; width: 0;` But that might break your layout. Can't really say without seeing the code.

Comment: can you modify your HTML part?

Comment: Ok i get with #content {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

Comment: Thank´s for negatives points , as always the people here always help , incredible

Comment: @user3765800 The negative points are because your question is very unclear and difficult to understand. You haven't provided any code that would clarify things. People here want to be helpful but you have to help _us_ in order for us to help _you_.

Comment: does this solution work for you. http://jsbin.com/conobolu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change this Highslide example gallery: http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-thumbstrip-above.html to have four visible thumbnails in the page instead of one visible thumbnail. The clue is to move the markup for the thumbnails you want to be visible, outside the hidden-container div.

The example gallery has one thumbnail outside the hidden-container div (see the source code). 

jsFiddle with four visible thumbnails: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/Un4N7/ 
The HTML markup of a gallery with eight images, but only four visible thumbnails, will look like this:

```
<div class="highslide-gallery">
    <a href="large-image1.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(this)" />
        <img src="thumbnail1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>

    <a href="large-image2.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(this)" />
        <img src="thumbnail2.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>

    <a href="large-image3.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(this)" />
        <img src="thumbnail3.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>

    <a href="large-image4.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(this)" />
        <img src="thumbnail4.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>

    <div class="hidden-container">
        <a href="large-image5.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(this)" />
            <img src="thumbnail5.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

        <a href="large-image6.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(this)" />
            <img src="thumbnail6.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

        <a href="large-image7.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(this)" />
            <img src="thumbnail7.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

        <a href="large-image8.jpg" onclick="hs.expand(this)" />
            <img src="thumbnail8.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```